# Run heredoc script via su attached to the current tty

Tags: tty, su, stdin, here-document

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
sudo su <<EOF
select x in a b c; do echo "Selected $x"; break; done
EOF
```

However, it terminates without accepting input.

It works if I do this:

```
sudo su -c 'select x in a b c; do echo $x; break; done'
```

But it's nicer writing longer scripts with heredoc (yes I know it's nicer still to put them in a file).

I'm sure this is answered in various places, but I can't seem to hit the right bash/heredoc/tty/stdin search term combo.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: So, put it in a script?

Comment: ⬑ "I know it's nicer still to put them in a file".  For my use case, that's more of a workaround than a solution.

Comment: How about `sudo -s` instead of `sudo su`?

Comment: The problem is that `select` is trying to read the response to the prompt from the here-doc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `select` is trying to read from stdin, which is redirected to the here-doc. Since there's no response to the prompt there, it gets an error.

The solution is to redirect input back to the terminal within the here-doc.

```
sudo -s <<'EOF'
select x in a b c; do 
    echo "Selected $x"
    break
done </dev/tty
EOF
```

Also, you need to put quotes around `EOF` to prevent variable expansion in the here-doc. Otherwise it expands `$x` in the original shell, not in the subshell that gets the value from `select`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks :) Man, I must have tried every other permutation of piping and redirecting, in my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

One way with a file if you want the remainder run as something else

```
$ cat asdf
who am i
sudo su
who am i
$ bash < asdf
jhldoe   tty??    Jun  7 16:30 
root     tty??    Jun  7 16:30 
$
```

More simpler might be that shells given standard input will run those commands

```
$ sudo sh <<EOF
> who am i
> pwd
> EOF
root     tty??    Jun  7 16:31 
/var/tmp
$
```

For the problem of reading from standard input and also having access to the terminal, I can solve that with my [`feed`](https://github.com/thrig/scripts/blob/master/misc/feed) script ([documentation](https://github.com/thrig/scripts/blob/master/misc/feed.1), [unit tests](https://github.com/thrig/scripts/blob/master/misc/t/feed.t), [`.feedrc`](https://github.com/thrig/dotfiles/blob/master/.feedrc) file for root's home directory).

```
$ (echo 'select x in a b c; do echo "Selected $x"; break; done') | sudo feed - bash
```

Though this will leave you in a root shell, and shoves the input into that shell, so may or may not suit your need.

Comment: I want to avoid writing the script to a file, if possible.  Your second suggestion is interesting, but, like using `su`, it doesn't attach to my `stdin` so I can't select an option (e.g. `echo 'select x in a b c; do echo "Selected $x"; break; done' | sudo sh`).